# Streambuilder snapshot.hasData never gets true although there is data in snapshot

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, snapshot, stream-builder

In my App I want to fetch data from Firestore and show the snapshot on the screen. Therefore I am using Streambuilder and as soon as data is loaded I want to show it.

This is my Firebase Service Class:

```
class FireBaseHandler {
  final CollectionReference usersCol = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(
      'users');
  final myUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;

  /// get user plan doc stream
  Stream<UserPlan> get userPlan {
    return usersCol.doc(myUser.uid).collection('plans').doc('plana')
        .snapshots().map(_userPlanFromSnapshot);
  }

  /// userPlan from snapshot
  UserPlan _userPlanFromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
    print(snapshot.data());  /// here is data available
    return UserPlan(
      planId: 'plana',
      name: (snapshot.data() as Map)['name'],
      exerciseName: (snapshot.data() as Map)['exerciseName'],
      rows: (snapshot.data() as Map)['rows'],
    );
  }

}
```

Now I want to show data on screen with streambuilder:

```
body: StreamBuilder<UserPlan>(
          stream: FireBaseHandler().userPlan,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              UserPlan userPlan = snapshot.data;
              return ListView(
                children: [
                  ListTile(
                    title: Text(userPlan.name),
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) {
                            return ExerciseTable(title: userPlan.name, exerciseNumber: userPlan.exerciseName.length);
                          },
                        ),
                      );
                    }
                  )
                ],
              );
            } else {
              return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
            }
          })
```

The problem is that `snapshot.hasData` never gets true and I am stuck in the loading screen. But when I print the snapshot there is data available so why `snapshot.hasData` didn't get true?

Comment: add `print(snapshot)` before `if (snapshot.hasData) {` - what do you see on the logs?

Comment: AsyncSnapshot<UserPlan>(ConnectionState.waiting, null, null, null)

Comment: And i also got this line: AsyncSnapshot<UserPlan>(ConnectionState.active, null, type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Map<String, dynamic>>'

Comment: so you have `snapshot.hasError == true` and error is: *"List<dynamic> is not a subtype of type List<Map<String, dynamic>>"* - you should change `.snapshots().map` to `.snapshots().map<UserPlan>`

Comment: yes thank you this was the case

Answer (score 1):

Posting this as a community wiki, as this is based on the comments provided by @Pskink:

This error is occuring due to a mishandling of the casting of types of your snapshot map and you can fix it by changing `.snapshots().map()` to `.snapshots().map<UserPlan>()` in your stream creation.